# index.esm2017.js:370 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

***Complete error***

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at index.esm2017.js:10913
    at Y.<anonymous> (index.esm2017.js:10865)
    at qb (eventtarget.js:351)
    at D (eventtarget.js:481)
    at Z.wa (webchannelbasetransport.js:369)
    at sc (webchannelbase.js:2193)
    at tc (channelrequest.js:941)
    at M.k.Ia (channelrequest.js:619)
    at M.k.gb (channelrequest.js:596)
    at qb (eventtarget.js:351)
```

> Get
> https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel?database=projects%2Fnetflixclone-001%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&gsessionid=Il1qOZrt3xwI9HsitxL5j4_GdibS-ga9&VER=8&RID=rpc&SID=MgLGFVuM420X7FPF_SYqrg&CI=0&AID=0&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=fhlml28c0sd1&t=1
> net::ERR_FAILED 200

**Rules(cloud firestone)**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

**seedData Code(data.js)**

```
export function seedDatabase(firebase) {
    function getUUID() {
      // eslint gets funny about bitwise
    //    eslint-disable 
      return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, c => {
          const piece = (Math.random() * 16) | 0;
          const elem = c === 'x' ? piece : (piece & 0x3) | 0x8;
          return elem.toString(16);
      });
      /* eslint-enable */
    }
  
    /* Series
      ============================================ */
    // Documentaries
    firebase.firestore().collection('series').add({
      id: getUUID(),
      title: 'Tiger King',
      description: 'An exploration of big cat breeding and its bizarre underworld, populated by eccentric characters.',
      genre: 'documentaries',
      maturity: '18',
      slug: 'tiger-king',
    });
    firebase.firestore().collection('series').add({
      id: getUUID(),
      title: 'Amanda Knox',
      description: 'Amanda Marie Knox is an American woman who spent almost four years in an Italian prison.',
      genre: 'documentaries',
      maturity: '12',
      slug: 'amanda-knox',
    });
```

firebase.prod.js class

```
import Firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

// 1) when seeding the database you'll have to uncomment this!
import { seedDatabase } from '../data';

const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
  };

  const firebase = Firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// 2) when seeding the database you'll have to uncomment this!
seedDatabase(firebase);
// 3) once you have populated the database (only run once!), re-comment this so you don't get duplicate data

export { firebase };
```

*All other pages working fine*

Comment: Can you share code where your Firestore query can be seen? Also share your security rules.

Comment: its on console 
Promise.then (async)  
add @ database.ts:1273
seedDatabase @ data.js:475
./src/lib/firebase.prod.js @ firebase.prod.js:21
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:61
./src/index.js @ global-styles.js:18
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7

Comment: I don't see any code that makes a query. I can only see Firestore being initialized. Can you share your code which you are requesting any collection or document?

Comment: no i am just uploading data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your security rules just do not allow anyone to read or write to your database. If your set your rule to true as shown below, it should allow your to write:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /series/{document} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Now the problem is anyone on the internet can read or write to your series collection. It's hard for me to write rules for this since there's no detail about who can read/write to this collection. I'd recommend reading about [Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to restrict access to authorized users only.

Comment: Where should I put this?